# "Pushed" effect on button press

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have circular button as [image]

XAML for that is,

```
<!--round button-->
<Style x:Key ="roundButtonTemplate" TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property ="Margin" Value ="10,0,10,10"/>
    <Setter Property ="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name ="OuterRing" Width ="40" Height ="40" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property ="IsPressed" Value ="True">
                        <Setter TargetName ="OuterRing" Property ="Height" Value ="30"/>
                        <Setter TargetName ="OuterRing" Property ="Width" Value ="30"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I have applied it as,

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource roundButtonTemplate}" Click="button_Click" Background="#CC41B1E1" Width="42" Height="42" Margin="0,0,10,0">
     <Image Height="24" Width="24" Source="/Images/add.png" />
</Button>
```

Now the problem is when I press the button only the circle shrinks but the image remains as it is. I want the whole button to shrink with image as well to give it a perfect "Pushed" effect.
Any idea what is getting wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of changing size to some fixed value in you template apply `ScaleTransform` to main `Grid` of your template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType ="{x:Type Button}">
   <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="RootGrid">
      <Ellipse x:Name ="OuterRing" Width ="40" Height ="40" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property ="IsPressed" Value ="True">
         <Setter TargetName="RootGrid" Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

don't forget to set `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"`

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks! Can you explain a little what exactly is happening behind?

Comment: When `IsPressed` is true it will set `RenderTransform` of the main `Grid` (named, in this case, _RootGrid_) to `ScaleTransform` which will scale down the `Grid` to 90% of original size (both X and Y). `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` makes sure that centre point of transformation is centre of the `Grid` so it scales down to the centre of control.

Comment: `RenderTransform` does not affect actual size or location of the control only it's appearance so control won't really change size or location. You have different transforms at your disposal like `RotateTransform` to rotate by given angle or `TranslateTransform` to move control left/right and up/down by given value

Comment: For me RenderTransform alone was making it appear to move to the top left because it seems that is the buttons anchor point, adding what @dkozl mentioned fixed the issue and made it anchored to the center.